# Remove all numbers and dashes from text file?

Tags: perl, shell, text, command-line, command

I have an extremely large text file that I need to remove all numbers and dashes from.

Is there any way to do this all at once via command line or perl?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Nice little regex script that finds then replaces all numbers and dashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` is your friend, together with the `-d` option to delete.

```
tr -d '[0-9-]' < file
```

To update your file, you can do `tr -d '[0-9-]' < file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file`

Or also `sed`:

```
sed 's/[0-9-]//g' file
```

To update your file, you can use `sed -i.bak 's...' file`. This will perform in-place editing: `file` will be updated with the new content and a `file.bak` backup file will be created.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello this is -23 and 45 bla-bla
hello bye 23.
$ tr -d '[0-9-]' < a
hello this is  and  blabla
hello bye .
```

Comment: for completeness `perl -pe's/[\d-]//g' file`.

Comment: For real completeness `perl -pe tr/0-9-//d file`'. `tr///` gets the job done without needing to load the regex engine.

Comment: @DaveCross of course! Looking forward to your book!! `:)`

Comment: It's weird none of above commands work for me on MacOS, why is that?

Comment: @Raymond you can try with `cat file | tr ...`

Comment: Yes did, it worked. Thanks all for the help.